# Make AJAX request when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

First of all, I'm *not really* familiar with **JQuery** and **AJAX**. I came up with the following codes by trying everything I found on the web and honestly I don't quite understand all of it.

I wish to show a bootstrap modal which contains records from the database when a button is clicked.
My problem is that, when the page loads, it already opens up the modal instead of when the button is clicked.

```
<button id="modalData">Load Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Plantilla</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Item Code</th>
                            <th>New Item Code</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Station</th>                                    
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <c:forEach var="plantilla" items="${sessionScope.plantilla}">                                     
                            <tr>  
                                <td><c:out value="${plantilla.getItemCode()}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${plantilla.getNewItemCode()}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${plantilla.getPosition()}"/></td>
                                <td><c:out value="${plantilla.getStation()}"/></td>                                                                        
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>  
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my script:

```
$("#modalData").click(loadPlantilla());

$.when(loadPlantilla()).done(function() {
    $('#modal').modal('show');
});

function loadPlantilla() {                
    return $.ajax({
        url: './TryAjax',
        type: 'POST',
        error: function() {
            alert('Ajax readyState: ' + xhr.readyState + '\nstatus: ' + xhr.status + ' ' + err);
        }
    });
}
```

And this is my Servlet:

```
PlantillaViewDao dao = new PlantillaViewDao();
List<PlantillaView> plantilla = dao.read();

HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("plantilla", plantilla);
```

Comment: $.when executes your method... thats why it is shown on pageload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the function immediately instead of passing a reference.

```
$("#modalData").click(loadPlantilla);
```

Also use `.done` on your ajax request:

```
function loadPlantilla() {                
    $.ajax({
        url: './TryAjax',
        type: 'POST',
        error: function() {
            alert('Ajax readyState: ' + xhr.readyState + '\nstatus: ' + xhr.status + ' ' + err);
        }
    }).done(function() {
        $('#modal').modal('show');
    });
}
```

**Have a quick look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tq3ghebL/).**

Comment: Why does the `.click(loadPlantilla);` doesn't have `()`? It seems that when it has `()` it calls the method on page load.

Comment: Because you are passing a reference - it's a callback method. It gets called when the link is clicked. the `()` executes the method so the return value of this method would be passed.

Answer (score 1):

$.when executes your method... thats why it is shown on pageload.

```
function loadPlantilla() {                
    $.ajax({
        url: './TryAjax',
        type: 'POST'
    }).done(function() {
        $('#modal').modal('show');
      });
}
```

You got to do something like this.

Or if you really want to use $.when ( maybe because your got more than one ajax call ) like this:

```
$("#modalData").click(function() {
    $.when(loadPlantilla(), method2(), method3()).done(function() {
        $('#modal').modal('show');
    });
});
```

Comment: I only have one ajax call. I didn't know that `when` is for making multiple ajax calls. Like what I've said, i'm just starting to learn JQuery and AJAX. I've replaced my `loadPlantilla()` method with what you suggested and It's not showing the modal on load anymore. But the problem is when I clicked the button. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: i edited my code. Actually you should think about your "error" code again. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ . As you see 3 parameters get passed to the function `Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )`.